# Sending Pdf via email in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, wicked-pdf

```html
emp_ids = params[:employee_ids]
```

I am working on a project in rails where i have an Employee List page,This list is the List of Salaryslip of an employee.In that list i have applied checkboxes and at the bottom there is an Send button.I want that if i select multiple checkboxes,Email should be gone to all the employees including the pdf of salary slip.I am able to do this if i select checkbox the on clicking on submit all the salaryslip come for the employee who i have selected but in that pdf page i can't apply email functionality so i want it to be directly happen.I have used wicked pdf and actionmailer but i'm confused how may i send an array of multiple employees ids(like this i have written in my index page [employee_ids] and accessed it using params[:employee_ids] in controller) to Action Mailer for send email.

Comment: when you check than each checked employee get salary his/her salary slip in mail right?

Comment: yes...i want that in email of every employee which i selected using checkbox.I have also written in ActionMailer but sdon know may i render so many pdf in email.

Comment: do anyone knows how may i achieve this functionality??? i need it urgently....

Comment: why don't you iterate through the array of employee_ids and send a mail for each? Since email content differs, you cannot just say ActionMailer to send one email to different employees with different content. If content would be the same, of course you could send that one email to all different employees at once.

so why don't you just use something alike:
params[:employee_ids].each {|employee_id| YourSalaryMailer.send_salary_pdf(employee_id).deliver_now }

Comment: ok i'll try.....thanks for the reply.....!!!!!!

Comment: but how may i apply loops in it for sending email???? will you give an example....!!!!!

Comment: only want to the basic syntax of how may i iterate it.

Comment: if anyone knows the answer then pls reply...........!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
def generate_slip
  employees = Employee.where(id: emp_ids)
  employees.each do |employee|
   @employee = employee
   pdf_name = employee.name + Date.today.to_s
   pdf = render_to_string pdf: "pdf.html.erb", template: "employees/pdf.html.erb", layout: 'layouts/pdf', encoding: "UTF-8"
   file_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs',"#{pdf_name}.pdf")
   File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
     file << pdf
   end
   UserMailer.send_file(to: employee.email, subject: "Slip")
  end 
end
```

You need to create one folder called 'pdfs' into public directory and one file called 'pdf.html.erb' under employees directory.

All instance variable available into pdf.html.erb file.

Hope it will help you

Comment: to store generated pdf file, you can store anywhere you like

Comment: [4834, 5152, 5151, 5151, 5159, 5162, 5151, 5151, 5138, 5003, 4843, 5112, 4609, 4629, 5166, 4904, 4815, 4899, 4738, 4675, 4724, 4699, 4699, 4608, 4969, 4898, 5125, 4856, 4922, 4880, 4880, 5079, 4673, 4889, 4889, 4780, 4902, 4691, 4939, 4791, 4631, 5025, 4647, 4922, 4906, 4952, 4911, 4882, 4732, 5127, 4787, 4733, 4915, 5151, 5151, 4839, 5021, 4937, 4809, 4840, 5097, 4776, 4855, 4864, 4864, 4735, 4716, 4921, 4985, 4977, 5125, 4701, 4783, 4744, 4792, 5166, 4963, 4904, 4978, 4899, 4759]

Comment: this is my array....i want to count duplicate elements in array and display how many time that element is repeated...means 5151 is repeated 2 time.so it must display 5151=2

Comment: result = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |key,counts| counts[key] += 1 }

Comment: its in hash....how may i convert it into simple object so i may get....5151=6,4922=2 and so on...............

Comment: coz 5151 is employee id...so i want to dispay it like this....for eg 5151 name is abc...so it must come like this.........abc=2 and so on..........

Comment: you can't get directly into simple form you have to iterate over it.

Comment: @employee_leav_requests = EmployeeLeavRequest.where.not(first_reporter_id: nil).where(current_status: "Pending").pluck(:first_reporter_id)

Comment: if first reporter has 6 employees under it and  EmployeeLeavRequest is the table name.....then first_reporter_id may be common for many employee...so i want a name of employees whose

Comment: reporting manager is same.for eg [5151,{4605,4606,4607,4608}] here 5151 is first_reporter and it has 6 employee under him.

Comment: i have posted one question...reply in that....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270910/date-format-error-in-ruby-in-rails-4-with-sql-server-as-a-database-on-windows-7   @hardik