# DATE_FORMAT error in ruby in rails 4 with sql server 2014 as a database on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sql-server-2012

i am getting DATE_FORMAT error in ruby on rails with sql server as a database

```html
<% date = Date.today %>
<% @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth,'%d/%m') = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')) %>
```

Comment: i am getting the above error.so what's the specific format for sql server.

Comment: If you google _t-sql format date_ you will fin a multitude of answers. You should try to keep all data types date though - don't convert to string because you run into trouble.

Comment: will you convert mine above rails query to sql server supported rails query???

Comment: Use `FORMAT`, not `DATE_FORMAT`. See here for valid format strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql. I don't know what %d/%m is. Lastly: Its a *bad* idea to fiddle about with date formats. You should keep everything a date and not cast as strings. I don't know what parameters your `Employee.where` takes, but you should keep it a date in both your code and on the SQL Server side.

Comment: will you convert mine rails query into sql sever query for rails??

Comment: because i am getting error.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not going to rewrite your code for you. If you took the effort to post the error I might consider it but you're really not making any effort at all

Comment: i have put down an effort........still not able to convert my dateformat to sql server/...its giving error...

Comment: i tried using this  @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND FORMAT(date_of_birth,'%d/%m') = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m'))

Comment: thanks for your link...but i am unable to convert it..

Comment: '%d/%m' is not a valid format string for Format. I suggest you check the link again.

Comment: yaa...but how should i convert the query into sql server....coz it contains where query.....!!

Comment: `FORMAT(date_of_birth,'%d/%m')` is incorrect, because `'%d/%m'` is an invalid string for the FORMAT function. Try this instead: `FORMAT(date_of_birth,'dd/MM')`. If you get an error, post the error and also post the version of SQL Server.

Comment: did you also try `Employee.where("status = ? AND date_of_birth = ?", "Active" , date)`? This way you are leaving everything as dates and no formatting is required.

Comment: i have tried this now...but i am getting error....@employees = Employee.where(status: "Active" AND date_of_birth: CONVERT(date,getdate(),107)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140149/discussion-between-mahesh-sharma-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: i am getting this error.....irb(main):017:0> @employees = Employee.where(status: "Active" AND date_of_birth: CONVERT(date,getdate(),107))
SyntaxError: (irb):17: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'

Comment: its very urgent...will you let me know my mistake...!!!!!!!

Comment: i have tried................

Comment: i have also tried this by removing AND Keyword.......@employees = Employee.where(status: "Active",date_of_birth: CONVERT(date,getdate(),107))

Comment: There must be some kind of doco for `Employees.where` that tells you what parameters it takes

Comment: what doco??????

Comment: Here I'll find it for you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html It shows this syntax as one example: `Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])` At this stage you have tried many different syntaxes. You need to pick _one_ approach and experiment until you understand what's going and why it does or doesn't work. I can tell you in your current attempts you are mixing up T-SQL and ruby(?) syntax. Thats not going to work. The stuff inside the double quotes is T-SQL syntax. The stuff outside is ruby(?) syntax.

Comment: Here is one suggestion (but it invites SQL injection and is specifically warned against: `Employee.where("status = 'Active' AND FORMAT(date_of_birth,'dd/MM') = '" + date.strftime('%d/%m') + "'")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strftime error while switching my database from sqlite3 to mysql in Rails4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061570/strftime-error-while-switching-my-database-from-sqlite3-to-mysql-in-rails4)

Comment: YOU ALREADY ASKED THIS! AND IT WAS ANSWERED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<% date = Date.today %>
<% @employees = Employee.where("status = ? AND FORMAT(date_of_birth,'dd/MM','en-US') = ?", "Active" , date.strftime('%d/%m')) %>
```

Learn more about [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: my new question link.......answer me if you know.......... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320451/how-to-take-auto-backup-of-mysql-database-in-rails-4

Comment: why this code is not working...........@food_deductions = FoodDeduction.where("DATE_FORMAT('%Y/%m', food_date) = ?",date.strftime('%Y/%m'))