# How to take Auto backup of Mysql Database in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, whenever

I am using Rails 4 with Mysql2 as a database in Windows.I want to take auto backup of my database every second. So that there should be folder generated at every second in the path which i specify and also an email must be sent along with database as an attachment.I used whenever gem for this purpose but i am unable to get what i must write in my schedule.rb file.

```html
schedule.rb file

every :day, :at => '12:05am' do
  rake 'task_namespace:autobackup' , :environment => 'development',   :output => 'log/autobackup_mail.log'
  # rake 'task_namespace:autobackup_with_mail' , :environment => 'development',   :output => 'log/autobackup.log'
end
```

Comment: one more question....how's it possible to autobackup in mysql....as in mysql database is not visible as in sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gem Backup.

> Backup is a system utility for Linux and Mac OS X, distributed as a
>   RubyGem, that allows you to easily perform backup operations. It
>   provides an elegant DSL in Ruby for modeling your backups. Backup has
>   built-in support for various databases, storage protocols/services,
>   syncers, compressors, encryptors and notifiers which you can mix and
>   match. It was built with modularity, extensibility and simplicity in
>   mind.

you can visit:
http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/database-mysql/

Backup allows you to model your backup jobs using a Ruby DSL:

```
Backup::Model.new(:my_backup, 'Description for my_backup') do
  # ... Model Components ...
end
```

The :my_backup symbol is the model’s trigger and used to perform the job:

```
$ backup perform --trigger my_backup
```

it also support PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Redis, Riak, SQLite

Comment: you'd  better put it on the large disk

Comment: dat i know....but the whole process must be automatic..........!!!!!!!!!